# Excel 2016 combine subtotal and sumifs

Tags: microsoft-excel

My `SUMIFS` needs to add up column `D` (`D11:D172`) and the first criteria is a range called `qbplistcomp` (which is column `B` so `B11:B172`) for multiple hits (e.g. CHF, COPD, and all STROKE so using STROKE*) and the second criteria is in column `C` (`C11:C172`) looking for the criteria which is a label "qbp volumes" ... so far without subtotaling, this formula works as:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D11:D172,qbplistcomp,{"CHF","COPD","STROKE*"},C11:C172,"QBP Volumes"))
```

Now my column `A` has the ability to filter on Category, so if I choose say just "stroke" it should only subtotal (sum) just those ones ... keep getting error ... help, thanks, Tina

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1531719/edit) to provide us with sample data and expected outcome? Also, the `SUBTOTAL` formula you are trying would be useful

Comment: I agree with cybernetic.nomad, please share us with a sample and more information about **errror**, generally SUMIFS could sum all the data that meet your multiple criteria.